# Problems installing “sudo” under Debian 6

Tags: linux, debian, aptitude

I'm trying to install sudo on specialized computer that runs Debian 6 and got error:

```
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main sudo i386 1.7.4p4-2.squeeze.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sudo/sudo_1.7.4p4-2.squeeze.2_i386.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]
```

I suppose it is because of not supported sources list. There is no such file like `/etc/apt/sources.list`. But I have directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` which contains files with content:

```
cat multistrap-caenrfid-stable.list
    deb http://support.caenrfid.it/debian stable main
deb-src http://support.caenrfid.it/debian stable main

 multistrap-debian.list
    deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze main

multistrap-fallback.list
    deb http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny main
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny main

multistrap-webmin.list
    deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
```

What should I do in order to install `sudo` ?

Comment: @harrymc The problem come from the `sources.list` , an EOL debian distro is only acceded from archive.

Answer (score 0):

Debian Squeeze is an End Of Live Debian distribution. According to [the debian doc](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSqueeze) your sources.list should contain only the following lines:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main
```

You are using a mixed sources.list and may cause some dependencies problem.

Create the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file as described above and remove the files under the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory then run (as root) :

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install sudo
```

[Distribution Archives](https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive#old-archive)